# LoadContentFrom with dynamic route value

Tags: dynamic, kendo-ui

Is it possible to specify a dynamic route value in the Kendo UI tabstrip `LoadContentFrom(string ActionName, string ControllerName, Object routeValues)` method?  I want to embed the tabstrip into a page which will show different customers and change the customer data (including ID) via AJAX.  That will mean my tabstrip only works for the first customer.

```
@Code
Html.Kendo().TabStrip() _
    .Name("tabstrip") _
    .Items(Sub(tabstrip)
                   tabstrip.Add().Text("Tasks") _
                       .Selected(True) _
                       .LoadContentFrom("List", "Task", New With {.CustomerID = Model.CustomerID})

                   tabstrip.Add().Text("Contacts") _
                       .LoadContentFrom("List", "Contact", New With {.ContactID = Model.CustomerID}) _
    .Render()
End Code
```